# Is this a proper div layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Ok so I am trying to make a layout to be used with Contact Form 7. This is what I have come up with, I just feel like I could probably clean it up. Also I cant seem to remove my Submit class without breaking everything.

I want to get rid of:

```
.Submit {
float:right;
}
```

I also would like to get the columns to line up properly. I have them lined up if the screen is the right size but I would like to make this responsive if possible.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qUdd/)

Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Thanks,

jFlatz

Comment: Why not use a table instead of mimicking one with divs ?

Comment: because tables aren't for layouts, tables are for tabular data, although it may be a divided opinion, I don't believe forms fall under tabular data

Comment: @andymccullough `.table` `.cell` `.row` you're kidding right ?

Comment: they're class names, so what, they could be called apple, bananas and pears, the difference is you are not limited to a HTML table element for any future changes that may want to break away from a table-like structure

Comment: I was corrected before for using tables for design. So I was trying to do it "more better" lol. My big problem was I forgot a curly bracket. Any advice on making the whole thing more responsive?

Comment: @andymccullough, What is causing the spacing between the left and right rows? http://jsfiddle.net/BKuBg/ Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using 2 x `width:49.5%;`, totalling 99%.  If you want no gap, use `width:50%; display:inline-block;` and remove the whitespace in your markup, i.e. `<div>city</div><div>state</div>`, but personally I would use floats instead of inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
.table width: 70%;

}
```

you left out a `{`, i.e.

```
 .table {
    width: 70%;        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I missed the open curly bracket. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qUdd/4/)

You can get rid of that .Submit rule safely if you open/close the .table rule above it appropriately:

THIS...

```
}
.table width: 70%;

}
.Submit {
    float:right;
}
```

Should Be...

```
}
.table {
    width: 70%;
    }

.Submit {
    float:right;
}
```